# Custom Nameserver (Hostname) Registration

Tags: domain-name-system, nameserver, hostname

I have done enough research and I feel that a solution specific to my problem doesn't exist or I'm unable to find an easy option to choose. So I'm going to offer my clients managed hosting using third-party web services. The issue I'm facing is regarding the custom nameservers. As I'll be offering VPS machines to my clients, so I want to register custom nameservers for each VPS and the nameservers should be on my main domain. Domain registrars offer the feature to register custom nameservers or hostnames, but is this possible to use a DNS server to register my custom nameservers? Is the registrar only entity that can handle this for me? If there is a solution, please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is the registrar only entity that can handle this for me?

Yes. And even not "the registrar" but "each and every registrar" used by your clients domain names (they are free to register them everywhere or you handle everything yourself? Not clear from your question...)

You seem to be confused about what "registering" a nameserver means, and that can be easy (to be confused) as there is a lot of misinformation. So the below will just answer that specific part, but other than that nowadays doing DNS for any kind of non-trivial setup might not be a good idea to start with without any kind of experience of low level DNS protocol working, shell scripting, monitoring, automating, etc. especially with more complex technologies like DNSSEC.

First, a caveat that you may not like: most often this is done for vanity reason and/or trying to hide the true hosting, and in both cases it does not work. So the real solution to your problem would be to just give your clients your nameservers as `ns1.my-shiny-hosting-company.example` and `ns2.my-shiny-hosting-company.example` and forget about creating nameservers per website hosted. You then regain a lot of time and sanity by going this simpler route.

Now more details about really this registering nameserver stuff, if you still want to do that or at least to understand better what that is.

First some important differences to note upfront:

- it depends on the TLD considered (the TLD of the domain using those nameservers, not the TLD of the nameservers)
- it depends on using "in-bailiwick" nameservers or not, that is nameservers whose names are below the domain name **for which they are authoritative** (this clause is very important). `ns1.example.com` is in-bailiwick for `example.com` if `example.com` uses it as authoritative nameserver.

Obviously, if for any domain you want to host a website one you also want to have nameservers using the same name, then all of these nameservers are "in-bailiwick" and you are immediately in the most complex case to register them, let us see why now.

Registries use two separate models to handle nameservers: as objects, or as attributes. gTLDs use objects, many/most(?) ccTLDs use attributes. And things sometimes change (like `.FR` went from attributes to objects recently). This is mostly hidden normally from you by your registrar.

But in typical "objects" case things goes like this:

- you go to some registrar
- you register domain X
- before being able to set some nameservers to it, you need to register these nameservers: they need to exist as object in the registry database, so the registrar needs to create them first, and then associate them to your domain
- of course a good registrar hides all of this to you: it asks for your nameservers and then does what is needed transparently
- 3 cases happen:

  - if the nameserver name is in another TLD(s) than the one of the registry, it is called an "external" nameserver, and only its name is needed to create it as registry
  - if the nameserver name is in one TLDs of the registry, it is of couse an "internal" nameserver, so its name is needed and its IP addresses MAY be needed or not:

    - if the nameserver is directly under the domain name for which it has to be authoritative (that is the "in-bailiwick" case explained above), it MUST be created with IP addresses (for the resolution later to work, this is what created "glue" records at registry
    - if not, it may or may not be created with IP addresses, because they are not needed right now, but might be needed as soon as it is associated with the domain as authoritative.

So, in short, the registrar may ask you for IP addresses besides the nameservers names and then do its magic to create properly things at the registry.

As you see, you need to do that at least per (registrar, registry) couple: in some registries external nameservers are created per registrar, in some others there is one object shared for all.

If you go to the "attributes" case the discussion above about IP addresses and such still holds, the only thing different is that nameservers are not created as separate objects at the registry database, they are just provided as attributes to any command that creates or updates a domain name.

But in all cases the drawbacks of all that if you decide to go the route of "let us create a `ns1` and `ns2` under all domains we host" means:

- you need to get access to the registrar handling those domains to potentially define those names, and their IP addresses. So either you need to ask your clients to do the operation (if you do not manage their domain names registrations for them) - and good luck explaining all the above for them, of course each registrar website is different so to know where to go to register a nameserver will depend: I know some registrars where there is only one link to register a given nameserver to "all" registries (that is all registries where this specific registrar is accredited) which is most of the times certainly something you do not want, and others where there is no GUI to do that you need to ask the support), or do it for them but then you need their access to registrar panel (huge security risk)
- and you need to update all of that, and besides specific case (like if you handled all of your customers domain names registrations and if they were all at the same registrar), there are no bulk operations. So the day you will need to create a new `ns3`, you will need to do it everywhere (but same case indeed if you just create `ns3.my-shiny-hosting-company.example`), but even bigger problem the day you need to change the nameservers IP addresses (because this always happen) since by definition of creating them under the domain name they are authoritative for, they are in bailiwick so you will need to update the IP addresses not twice (in your own zonefile and maybe at registry for `my-shiny-hosting-company.example`) but as many times as they are domains, again asking each and every of your client to see where to do that at the registrar webpanel or doing that for them.

Expect major headaches going that route. Especially if you are not already an expert in the DNS hosting and the domain name registration businesses.

Comment: Thank you so much for your explanation. I feel that I failed to clarify the situation clearly. I don't want to register nameservers on users' domains, instead I want to set up custom nameservers for my own domain and give the nameservers to users. As I'm not going to use a single server, so I need to create a set of nameservers on my domain for each VPS that I provision to my client. I used name.com API and achieved what I wanted. Your answer completely answers my all confusions now. Thank you so much again.

Answer (score 2):

> So I'm going to offer my clients managed hosting using third-party web
>   services.
>
> I'll be offering VPS machines to my clients.

So you'll be offering website and VPS hosting?

If so, LEAVE THEIR DNS ALONE!

There's no technical reason you should host their DNS. If you don't have the requisite highly available and globally diverse infrastructure for hosting their DNS, and if you don't have the requisite knowledge and experience (Which you don't by virtue of your question) then you should not be hosting their DNS.

This is not meant as an insult to you. Leave the DNS hosting to the entities that have the infrastructure and experience. There's no reason for you to host DNS for your clients and you should not host DNS for your clients.

Comment: Does this answer follow the StackExchange guidelines? Is this an answer really? I could appreciate this as a comment. BTW yep, I'm not a networking expert but as I'll be selling WHM and cPanale hosting on VPS, I need to set up custom name servers or disable the DNS at WHM completely. BTW thank you for your comment.

Answer (score 1):

Typically, one registers only a single set of nameservers (again typically, under YOUR domain name), and then all your customer domains reference those nameservers as authoritative.  While you can register different nameservers for each customer domain, it's unnecessary, plus it's a pain to manage and migrate.  The drawbacks might seem small when you have three or four domains, but when you get to 20 or 200, registering separate nameservers (generally a minimum of 2 per domain) quickly becomes unwieldy.

Comment: Thank you, regarding the management, I'll automate the nameserver creation and deletion etc.